# Getting data returned from a function with a fetch request

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am using js fetch request.
I have this inside a function, when I call the function I want it to return my data.
This is not happening.
It would appear that the promise is not getting 'resolved'.

I clearly don't fully understand promises, so any advice on that in relation to the below example would be very useful.

Here is my sample code:

```
const test = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  const data = await response.json()
  return data;
}

console.log(test())
```

Output:

```
// [object promise]
{}
```

Question: How can I write the fetch request so that when I run `test()`, it returns me the json as I would expect?

Thank you

Comment: You need to await `test()` or use `.then` to get the value

Comment: @evolutionxbox - thanks, await test how? _ I am already awaiting data, which should be returned no?

Comment: Instead of `cosnole.log(test())` write `test().then(console.log)`

Comment: @Shikhar - Thank you, I see I can log the results, but what if I wanted to use the results? I mean to say - In another function, I simply want to get those results.
Which is why I like to call the function and simply have it return those results. Is this possible or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You can use the results like this, `test().then((response)=>/*do something here*/ console.log(response))`

Comment: @Shikhar I just want to save the results, they will be called by another function at a later point.

Comment: So for that you can declare on global variable and save the response in that variable in then function. Something like: 
`let response = []; test().then((res)=>response = Array.from(res))`